# Simplify Re[z] in equation to more "natural" form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

If you have a triangle in the complex plane with vertexes {a,b,c} (all 
complex numbers), the length of the altitude from A to the side BC can 
be computed as:

`Abs[-a + b + (-b + c)*Re[(-a + b)/(b - c)]]`

While technically correct, the `Re` bugs me.

Since we're in the complex plane, I believe there's a more natural way 
to write the formula above, one that doesn't involve looking at the 
components of an imaginary number.

I've tried several things (including Simplify, FullSimplify, 
TrigReduce, etc) to no avail.

How can I cleanup this formula to look more natural and less dependent 
on imaginary components?

Comment: You know about `ComplexExpand[]`, no?

Comment: Well yes, but doesn't ComplexExpand[] assume all it's variables are real numbers? In my case, a, b, and c are all complex. I've now come up with `Re[z] -> (z+Conjugate[z])/2`, which helps, but still seems ugly.

Comment: To me the `Re` indicates an orthogonal projection, which seems a natural operation when finding a (perpendicular) altitude.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If one side of the triangle is aligned with the real (or complex) axis, this makes sense. However, for an arbitrary triangle, there's no reason Re[z] should show up.

Comment: Dividing by `b-c` can be seen as a rotation (with scaling), followed by the projection `Re`, then rotated (and scaled) back by the multiplication by `-b+c`.  At least that's how I was seeing it.  -- But just to be clear, there may be a more natural form such as you seek. (I don't know what it is.)

Comment: You say "I believe there's a more natural way to write the formula". Perhaps so, perhaps not. However, what would be more natural is a matter of opinion and a mathematical issue, not a _Mathematica_ one. I don't see this post as being an reasonable question for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: You have here what IIRC is called the cosine theorem. `Re` of a complex number is its magnitude times the cosine of its argument. You simply found the angle between two sides of the triangle. You can also use `Abs` and `Arg` if you like that better, then you'll get an explicit `Cos[Arg[...]]` in the answer.

Comment: Barry, FWIW, here's an illustration of what I mean: `Module[{a, b, c, polys}, SeedRandom[2]; polys = FoldList[#2[[1]][#, #2[[2]]] &, {a, b, c}, {{Subtract, a}, {Divide, b - c}, {{#1, {#1[[2]], Re[#1[[2]]]}} &, {}}, {Times, c - b}, {Plus, -a + b}}]; {a, b, c} = RandomComplex[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 3]; Graphics[{ EdgeForm[Black], Red, Polygon[ReIm@#] }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3] & /@ polys ]`, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

You can get an expression using `ComplexExpand` that removes the `Re` by writing out each of the `a`, `b`, and `c` as explicit complex numbers:

```
eqn = Abs[-a + b + (-b + c)*Re[(-a + b)/(b - c)]] /. 
           {a -> a1 + I a2, b -> b1 + I b2, c -> c1 + I c2}
FullSimplify@ComplexExpand[eqn]
```

[image]

The answer avoids both the `Abs` and the `Re` functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. After the above (even after simplifying), I have Re[a] and Im[a] all over the place, just with different names.

Comment: Of course you have the real and imaginary parts present -- the answer depends on them. This just displays it without the explicit Re or Abs.